# Formal Languages - Expressive power of Formalisms

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, regular-expressions, pushdown-automata

I need help with the following question:

Order the following formalisms according to their expressive power:
placing A before B means that any language definable by A is definable
by B. Also state which, if any, of them are equivalent.

```
• Turing Machines (TM)
• Regular expressions (reg.exp.)
• Turing Machines with multiple tapes (TM+)
• Pushdown Automata (PDA)
• Nondeterministic Finite Automata with ǫ-transitions (NFAǫ)
• Nondeterministic Finite Automata (NFA)
• LR(1) grammars
• Nondeterministic Turing Machines (NTM)
• Deterministic Pushdown Automata (DPDA)
• Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA)
• Context-free Grammars (CFG)
```

Is this the correct answer ? I have a exam next week and need to know If my answer is correct.

```
NFAe=NFA=DFA=Reg.exp, LR(1)-Grammar=DPDA, CFG=PDA, TM=NTM=TM+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Formal_languages_and_grammars

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NFAe=NFA=DFA=Reg.exp, LR(1)-Grammar=DPDA, CFG=PDA, TM=NTM=TM+

Seems OK to me.